# ESBuild post-install failed when installing Vite

Tags: javascript, node.js, vite, pnpm, esbuild

I am using Vite as a bundler for a Nodejs project. When first installing Vite, everything is fine. But when I tried to install other packages again, I ran into the following error:

```
node_modules/esbuild postinstall$ node install.js
│ node:internal/errors:867
│   const err = new Error(message);
│               ^
│ Error: Command failed: /usr/local/bin/node /Volumes/Data/Develop/waterial-react/node_modules/esbuild/bin/esbuild --version
│ /Volumes/Data/Develop/waterial-react/node_modules/esbuild/bin/esbuild:1
│ ����
│ SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
│     at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
│     at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:20)
│     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1203:27)
│     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1293:10)
│     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1096:32)
│     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:935:12)
│     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:84:12)
│     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
│ Node.js v19.4.0
│     at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:885:11)
│     at Object.execFileSync (node:child_process:921:15)
│     at validateBinaryVersion (/Volumes/Data/Develop/waterial-react/node_modules/esbuild/install.js:96:28)
│     at /Volumes/Data/Develop/waterial-react/node_modules/esbuild/install.js:281:5 {
│   status: 1,
│   signal: null,
│   output: [
│     null,
│     Buffer(0) [Uint8Array] [],
│     Buffer(662) [Uint8Array] [
│        47,  86, 111, 108, 117, 109, 101, 115,  47,  68,  97, 116,
│        97,  47,  68, 101, 118, 101, 108, 111, 112,  47, 119,  97,
│       116, 101, 114, 105,  97, 108,  45, 114, 101,  97,  99, 116,
│        47, 110, 111, 100, 101,  95, 109, 111, 100, 117, 108, 101,
│       115,  47, 101, 115,  98, 117, 105, 108, 100,  47,  98, 105,
│       110,  47, 101, 115,  98, 117, 105, 108, 100,  58,  49,  10,
│       239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189,
│         7,  10,  10,  10,  83, 121, 110, 116,  97, 120,  69, 114,
│       114, 111, 114,  58,
│       ... 562 more items
│     ]
│   ],
│   pid: 8362,
│   stdout: Buffer(0) [Uint8Array] [],
│   stderr: Buffer(662) [Uint8Array] [
│      47,  86, 111, 108, 117, 109, 101, 115,  47,  68,  97, 116,
│      97,  47,  68, 101, 118, 101, 108, 111, 112,  47, 119,  97,
│     116, 101, 114, 105,  97, 108,  45, 114, 101,  97,  99, 116,
│      47, 110, 111, 100, 101,  95, 109, 111, 100, 117, 108, 101,
│     115,  47, 101, 115,  98, 117, 105, 108, 100,  47,  98, 105,
│     110,  47, 101, 115,  98, 117, 105, 108, 100,  58,  49,  10,
│     239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189,
│       7,  10,  10,  10,  83, 121, 110, 116,  97, 120,  69, 114,
│     114, 111, 114,  58,
│     ... 562 more items
│   ]
│ }
│ Node.js v19.4.0
└─ Failed in 1.3s at /Volumes/Data/Develop/waterial-react/node_modules/esbuild
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I am using pnpm as the package manager. I've found the issue [esbuild #1703](https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/1703), [#1953](https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/1953) and [#1711](https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/1711) that might be related to this but didn't help much. I've tried to update Node.js to `v19.4.0` but it didn't help.

I am using Storybook with pnpm which requires the following `.npmrc`:

```
auto-install-peers=true
legacy-peer-deps=true
node-linker=hoisted
ignore-workspace-root-check=true
```

I don't know if this caused the issue. I tried to remove `node_modules` and do a clean install again and it worked. But I'm wondering if there's a solution to fix this entirely without removing `node_modules` every time I install something.

I am using `vite@^4.0.4` (latest) and `pnpm@7.25.0` (also latest).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error and fixed it by running:

```bash
npm install --save-dev --ignore-scripts esbuild@<vite-peerdependency-version>
```

I don't think this is a permanent solution, but it fixed it for me.

EDIT:

I found a more permanent solution, I downgraded my Node version `16.11.1` and that fixed it. This solution worked on multiple computers.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this happening when multiple dependencies in a project require esbuild (especially when separate dependencies require different versions of esbuild). Try finding a common version of esbuild that works for all of the dependencies in your repo and set an `"overrides": { "esbuild": "x.y.z" }` in your package.json (npm 8.1.x or higher is required to use overrides). Personally I've had the most luck finding the lowest common version that works for all dependencies, in some cases I've had to pin back the vite version to use a compatible version of esbuild as other build tools in the repo. Try to get it so when you `npm ls esbuild` it shows `(deduped)` for everything past the first time esbuild is referenced, and no version incompatibles.

============

Edit: My conclusion above was incorrect. The root cause was my company's on-prem npm registry, the node_modules/esbuild/bin/esbuild file was corrupted. If you're experiencing this issue then compare the bin/esbuild file from the public npm with your company's npm and see if you can get library re-uploaded. In my case the bin/esbuild file for our on-prem solution somehow became an actual binary that as 9mb. The one that comes from the public npm registry is only 9kb and is a node/shell script that's plainly readable.

https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/3387